# Take a value 1-31 and convert it to ordinal date w/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, web, frontend

Is there a JavaScript code snippet to take a value of 1-31 and convert it to 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function getOrdinal(n) {
    var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
    v=n%100;
    return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
```

Thanks @RobG
bit modified version

```
function getOrdinal(n) {
    if((parseFloat(n) == parseInt(n)) && !isNaN(n)){
        var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
        v=n%100;
        return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
    }
    return n;     
}
```

Tests

```
getOrdinal("test");   // test
getOrdinal(1.5);      // 1.5
getOrdinal(1);        // 1st
getOrdinal(2);        // 2nd
getOrdinal(3);        // 3rd
getOrdinal(4);        // 4th
getOrdinal(true);     // true
getOrdinal(Infinity); // Infinity
getOrdinal(NaN);      // NaN
getOrdinal(void 0);   // undefined
```

Comment: Wow, did I stumble into Code Golf by mistake? :)

Comment: Also returns `1.5th`, `udnefinedth`, `NaNth`, `trueth` and `falseth` which might be quaint but seem less than useful. The function should probably test that the input is a number or suitable string (making sure it's an integer might be sufficient). If it is, return the number plus ordinal. Otherwise, return the original value.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it convenient to monkey-patch the function into the Number prototype, so you can call it as a method on the number (implementation shamelessly stolen from Pradeep's answer):

```
Number.prototype.toOrdinal = function() {
  var n = this.valueOf(),
      s = [ 'th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd' ],
      v = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(v-20)%10] || s[v] || s[0])
}
```

Example use:

```
var someDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31 + 1);
alert(someDay.toOrdinal())
```

Or you may believe that Monkey Patching Is Evil; as usual, YMMV.

(I sometimes call this particular method `th`, but that works somewhat better in languages where you don't need the parentheses for invocation.)

Adding an explanation of the logic.  Key points that are Javascript-specific:

1. The `%` operator returns negative results for a negative dividend modulo a positive divisor (so `-1 % 5` is `-1`; many other implementations of the modulus operator return only answers between `0` and `n-1`, so `-1 % 5` is `4`).
2. Attempting to index an array by a value outside the valid range of indexes (either negative or past the end of the array) results in the `undefined` value, which is falsey.

The logic exploits these facts to return the correct suffix from a compact expression with these parts.

1. Try to access `s[(v-20)%10]`. If `v` (which is the given number modulo 100) is less than 20, then the index is negative and the array access returns `undefined`.  Otherwise, the array index is between 0 and 9.  Values 0 through 3 return the correct associated suffix ("th", "st", "nd", and "rd"), while anything greater than 3 will again return `undefined`.
2. If the result of 1 is a defined value, return it; otherwise, try to access `s[v]`.  If `v` is itself 0, 1, 2, or 3, we again get "th", "st", "nd", or "rd" respectively. Otherwise, we get an undefined value, and the expression moves on to the next alternative.
3. If neither of the above results is defined, we return `s[0]`, which is "th".

The result is that everything from 4 through 20 - including 11, 12, and 13 - gets a "th", while all other numbers ending in 1, 2, or 3 get "st", "nd", and "rd", respectively.

Comment: Adding to `Number.prototype` has the benefit that it should only be called on values that are actually numbers. But it should test that the value is an integer, otherwise don't add the ordinal (and return the original value?).

Comment: I have a quick question why `v-20` and not just v?

Comment: I copied that from @PradeepSanjaya's answer, but it's there to deal with the fact that numbers ending in 1, 2, and 3 get "st", "nd", and "rd" - except for numbers ending in 11, 12, and 13, which all get "th".

Answer (score 1):

Pradeep's answer is cool, but something a bit more robust should test the value and do something sensible if it's not a suitable value for adding an ordinal (like just return the value), e.g.

```
var getOrdinal = (function() {

    var re = /^\d+$/;
    var ordinal = ["th","st","nd","rd"];

    return function (value) {

      var t;

      if (re.test(String(value))) {
        t = value % 100;
        return t + (ordinal[(t - 20 % 10)] || ordinal[t] || 'th');            
      }

      return value;
    }
}());

getOrdinal( void 0 );  // undefined
getOrdinal(        );  // undefined
getOrdinal( NaN    );  // NaN
getOrdinal( true   );  // true
getOrdinal( 1.0    );  // 1st
getOrdinal( ''     );  // '' (empty string)
getOrdinal(Infinity);  // Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install ordinal
```

Works in both the browser and node. Then just:

```
var ordinal = require('ordinal')

ordinal(1);   //=> '1st'
ordinal(2);   //=> '2nd'
ordinal(3);   //=> '3rd'
ordinal(4);   //=> '4th'

ordinal(11);  //=> '11th'
ordinal(12);  //=> '12th'
ordinal(13);  //=> '13th'

ordinal(21);  //=> '21st'
ordinal(22);  //=> '22nd'
ordinal(23);  //=> '23rd'
ordinal(24);  //=> '24th'
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ordinal