# Highcharts - Custom format for dateTimeLabelFormats (1st hour, 2nd hour....)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with Area graph.

How can I customize `xAxis label` as hourly basis with **suffix** as `1st, 2nd, 3rd` etc...?

> **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6nz0sod1/)**

[image]

**Current format:**

`01th hour, 02th hour, 03th hour` ....

**This has to be changed as below:**

`1st hour, 2nd hour, 3rd hour`....

I have tried to convert as above by using **ordinal** method, but not working though...

**May be placing the ordinal script is wrong?**

```
var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
          v=n%100;
      return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(function (n) {

  // Everything in common between the charts
  var commonOptions = {
    colors: ['#fe5758', '#99cc03', '#33b5e6', '#fd8f40', '#e7ca60', '#40abaf', '#f6f7f8', '#e9e9eb'],
    chart: {
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: '#585858',
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: null
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          color: "#000",
        }
      },
      labels: {
        style:{ color: '#000' }
      },
      lineColor: '#e4e4e4',
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickLength: 0,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          color: "#000",
        }
      },
      offset:-6,
      labels: {
        style:{ color: '#bbb' }
      },
      tickInterval: 100,
      lineColor: '#e4e4e4',
      lineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
    },
    series: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.5)",
    }],

    // Area Chart
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        lineWidth: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1.5,
          symbol: 'circle',
          fillColor: 'white',
        },
        legend: {
          radius: 2,
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      shared: true,
      backgroundColor: '#5f5f5f',
      borderWidth: 0,
      style: {
        padding:10,
        color: '#fefefe',
      }
    },
    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12',
        color: '#666666',
      },
      marker: {
        symbol: 'square',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        radius: '4',
      },
      symbolHeight: 6,
      symbolWidth: 6,
    },
  };

  $('#areaChartTwoWay-time').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(commonOptions, {
    chart: { type: 'area' },
    xAxis: {
      title: { text: 'Hours', },
      type: 'datetime',
      min:Date.UTC(2016,04,16,1,0,0,0),
      minRange: 12 * 3600 * 500,
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: '%Hth hour',
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      tickInterval: 30,
      title: { text: 'Total views', },
      offset:0,
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Unique open',
      lineColor: '#fb8b4b',
      marker: { lineColor: '#fb8b4b', fillColor: 'white', },
      data: [88, 68, 79, 39, 48, 69, 69, 18, 40, 62, 91, 61, 39],
      legendIndex:1,
      pointInterval: 3600 * 500,
      pointStart:Date.UTC(2016,04,16,1,0,0,0), 
    }, {
      name: 'Forwards',
      lineColor: '#99cc03',
      marker: { lineColor: '#99cc03', fillColor: 'white', },
      data: [3, 8, 15, 12, 61, 32, 43, 18, 9, 12, 22, 18, 12],
      legendIndex:0,
      pointInterval: 3600 * 500,
      pointStart:Date.UTC(2016,04,16,1,0,0,0),        
    }]
  }));

  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
      v=n%100;
  return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);

  $('.highcharts-grid > path:last-child').remove();
  $('.highcharts-markers > path:last-child').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call another function to get the ordinal. A quick google found this method:

```html
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
```

This takes a number and returns a string, which is made up of the number with he correct ordinal appended.

This won't work with dateTimeLabelFormats though. For your use, you could use a simple label formatter.

I've updated your online demo here also:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nz0sod1/2/

Hope this helps

Source: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/ordinal-number-in-javascript-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-29259

Comment: Also, this question might be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487422/take-a-value-1-31-and-convert-it-to-ordinal-date-w-javascript

Comment: Hi **@George Harris**, thanks for the quick turnaround... as I am newbie to these scripts, I am confused about which place should I need to use... Tried adding at the bottom, but not working... Can you please update my answer for the same please?
**http://jsfiddle.net/6nz0sod1/1/**

Comment: Hi @Reddy, couldn't manage to get this working directly with dateTimeLabelFormats. I would recommend for your use here to use the normal label formatter, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/6na7gL0b/

I'll update my answer with reference to this