# Ordinal Date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display date as **04th Sep 2017**.

As is used in AngularJs view (html template)

```
Start Date :  {{info.start_date| date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}
```

It displays **04 Sep 2017** instead of **04th Sep 2017**.

Please help.

Comment: you may have a look here: [Take a value 1-31 and convert it to ordinal date w/ JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487422/take-a-value-1-31-and-convert-it-to-ordinal-date-w-javascript)

Comment: I'd go for a library like [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment), which is based on [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/). You can do something like `{{ info.start_date | date: 'Do MMMM YYYY' }}`. Should do the trick

Comment: Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/HiyQ9uvxQL3FRoj7hKB8?p=preview) Plunker.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a value 1-31 and convert it to ordinal date w/ JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487422/take-a-value-1-31-and-convert-it-to-ordinal-date-w-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn first what is [Ordinal number](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/vocabulary/numbers/ordinal). And you can do it by manually. I don't know moment.js have default function for ordinal date. So I have creating a custom filter here for ordinal date and number.

### Ordinal Date

```js
var app = angular.module('filters', []);

    app.controller('demo', function($scope){
      $scope.example1 = "04 Sep 2017";
       $scope.example2 = "12 Sep 2017";
        $scope.example3 = "23 Sep 2017";
    })

    app.filter('ordinalDate', function(){
      return function(date){
      var number=parseInt(date.split(" ")[0]);
      var MonthAndYear= " " + date.split(" ")[1] +" " + date.split(" ")[2];
        if(isNaN(number) || number < 1){
          return number;
        } else {
          var lastDigit = number % 10;
          if(lastDigit === 1){
            return number === 11 ? number + 'th' + MonthAndYear: number + 'st' + MonthAndYear;
          } else if(lastDigit === 2){
            return number === 12 ? number + 'th' + MonthAndYear: number + 'nd' + MonthAndYear;
          } else if (lastDigit === 3){
            return number === 13 ? number + 'th' + MonthAndYear: number + 'rd' + MonthAndYear;
          } else if (lastDigit > 3 || lastDigit === 0 ){
            return number + 'th' + MonthAndYear;
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
 body {
      background: White;
    }

    .credits {
      margin: 15px 0px;
    }

    .panel {
      margin: 15px 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
          <div ng-app="filters">
            <div ng-controller="demo">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                   <h4 class="text-center">AngularJS Filter - Ordinal Numbers</h4>
                   <p><strong>Original:</strong></p>
                   <ul class="list">
                     <li>{{example1}}</li>
                     <li>{{example2}}</li>
                      <li>{{example3}}</li>
                     
                   </ul>
                   <p><strong>Ordinal Date Filter:</strong></p>
                   <ul class="list">
                     <li>{{example1 | ordinalDate}}</li>
                     <li>{{example2 | ordinalDate}}</li>
                     <li>{{example3 | ordinalDate}}</li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row credits">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.scotch.io">Read Full Tutorial on Scotch.io</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Ordinal Number

Try this below way to achieve this.

```js
var app = angular.module('filters', []);

app.controller('demo', function($scope){
  $scope.example1 = 1;
  $scope.example2 = 2;
  $scope.example3 = 3;
  $scope.example4 = 4;
  $scope.example5 = 11;
  $scope.example6 = 12;
  $scope.example7 = 13;
  $scope.example8 = 14;
  $scope.example9 = 21;
  $scope.example10 = 32;
})

app.filter('ordinal', function(){
  return function(number){
    if(isNaN(number) || number < 1){
      return number;
    } else {
      var lastDigit = number % 10;
      if(lastDigit === 1){
        return number === 11 ? number + 'th': number + 'st'
      } else if(lastDigit === 2){
        return number === 12 ? number + 'th': number + 'nd'
      } else if (lastDigit === 3){
        return number === 13 ? number + 'th': number + 'rd'
      } else if (lastDigit > 3 || lastDigit === 0 ){
        return number + 'th'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: White;
}

.credits {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.panel {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div ng-app="filters">
        <div ng-controller="demo">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-body">
               <h4 class="text-center">AngularJS Filter - Ordinal Numbers</h4>
               <p><strong>Original:</strong></p>
               <ul class="list">
                 <li>{{example1}}</li>
                 <li>{{example2}}</li>
                 <li>{{example3}}</li>
                 <li>{{example4}}</li>
                 <li>{{example5}}</li>
                 <li>{{example6}}</li>
                 <li>{{example7}}</li>
                 <li>{{example8}}</li>
                 <li>{{example9}}</li>
                 <li>{{example10}}</li>
                 
               </ul>
               <p><strong>Ordinal Filter:</strong></p>
               <ul class="list">
                 <li>{{example1 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example2 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example3 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example4 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example5 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example6 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example7 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example8 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example9 | ordinal}}</li>
                 <li>{{example10 | ordinal}}</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row credits">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.scotch.io">Read Full Tutorial on Scotch.io</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```